# prevent navigation from url to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I will try to explain my problem. I have a webpage A, when I finish a process in A I can go to page B. When I finish a process on page B, I can go to page C. and thus I can have n number of pages. to page n.
I would like the user to never be able to access page C if he has not gone first to page A or page B. In other words I want to force the user to use the internal navigation of the page. that is to say that the user can not write the url in the browser, or reload the page, if this happens, it should be redirected to a specific page.

from angular with this managed to put some condition before going to any particular controller.

```
//similar to $statechange
angularRoutingApp.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $location, $transitions) 
{
$transitions.onStart({}, trans = > {
    $state.go('anystate', trans.targetState())
 });
}
```

and from javascript with this I get to know when a page is reloaded.

```
if ($window.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
 console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
} else {
console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

but in both cases I have a problem:
if I am in A and I have not finished the process and immediately from the browser url I write the url of B, it breaks the condition I want. but if I am in B and recharge again, it is now detected that the page has been reloaded.

I hope to make myself understood.

What I can do?

Comment: You should instead redirect from page 3 based on what data you have - if you don't have the data from page 1 + 2 (filled out by the user of if there is no input then a variable set by you when they navigate to the next page from the ui), then you redirect

Answer (score 0):

Angular is designed as a Single Page Application and does not like it when you refresh. For that, you need to **store your information** (in a session, cookie, etc.) and then do your actions once you know for certain where you are.

To handle the access to different pages I suggest using a **resolver** in your config. You would check your stored data and redirect  accordingly. Resolve deals with promises before your route changes, so it runs before `angularRoutingApp.run()`

Additionally, `$stateProvider` allows you to have nested pages with custom controllers, which can simplify your resolves. More about how to [inject the results from the parent resolve into the child resolve function](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states)